# Start project with node

Tags: angularjs, node.js

I downloaded project files for a node / angular site from github: 
https://github.com/lavinjj/angularjs-spinner

I'm trying to run the project from my local node server.  When I type web-server.js in the node console I can see in the console that the 'http server running at http://localhost:8000/

When I type http://localhost:8000/sample01/index.html, http://localhost:8000/sample01 i see file not found.

How do I run this project?

Comment: If you're down voting, please say why....geez....

Comment: Whoever downvotes these without explanation is a dick.  Just saying.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to run the `web-server.js` from the root of the project. I.E

```
$ git clone https://github.com/lavinjj/angularjs-spinner.git
$ cd angularjs-spinner
$ pwd
/home/user/angularjs-spinner
$ node scripts/web-server.js
```

Comment: I did this, I saw in the console that the http server was running.  I couldn't navigate to the website in my browser.  Am I missing something?

Comment: You have to make sure you are running the server from the root of the project. I'll edit my answer in case its not clear.

Comment: Just confirmed it works on my OSX machine running node v0.12.1